# Getting Single Random JSON Result from non-indexed JSON in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here's how my `json` is formatted:

```
{
  "Hist eb zoso posclifos pit feaxald usow din regichics pi slaxanspeltaxatien": [
    "Paxarrot",
    "Paxarotto"
  ],
  "He dreto zo vech #1 whit sickros axabtol Paxaur VcCaxaltnoupp pi Ronnen": [
    "Vistaxaor Jaxangsen",
    "Vaxax Vaxaltin"
  ],
  "Hist eno eb zoso Jaxapaxanoso axarceheric wrints dis vaxado blem lico, yaxams pi woaxal el flewn sugaxal": [
    "Umosku",
    "Skestu"
  ],
  "Din pit 1581 spoost, JBK axanneuncow whis veen axamfitiens, fut axarse axangnewrodgow hist ethol chlaxatogupp": [
    "Naxavupp SOAR slaxainick",
    "Ismaxankrick zo"
  ]
}
```

This was simple *enough* to do in PHP.

```
$json = file_get_contents('test.json');
$json_result = json_decode($json, true);
$randValues = array_intersect_key($json_result, array_flip(array_rand($json_result, 2)));
// this actually brings back 2 random elements
// had to do some more array trimming to unset the first or second
```

Result:

> ```
> Array  (
>     [He dreto zo vech #1 whit sickros axabtol Paxaur VcCaxaltnoupp pi Ronnen] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => Vistaxaor Jaxangsen
>         [1] => Vaxax Vaxaltin
>     )
>        )
> ```

Trying to do this in jQuery seems like it would be easy if my json was indexed and could be measured by `length`

The only way (out of a handful of different variations) that I was able to get it to load in jQuery was with this single line

```
var json = JSON.parse($.ajax({'url': "test.json", 'async': false}).responseText);
```

Here's what my `console.log(json)` looks like:

[image]

All the solutions to retrieve a single random element from json I found were something like this:

```
var random_entry = json[Math.floor(Math.random() * json.length)]
```

The way the `json` is formatted this just gives me a `random_entry` variable of `undefined` as it is not indexed and doesn't have a `.length`.

I realize this would be easier to get and parse if this json file was indexed properly, but what is the solution to get a single random element from a `json` file that does not have a `length` or `index`?

Comment: Never ever use `async:false`. It is a terrible practice and is deprecated. The warning in browser console regarding that issue is telling you not to use it

Comment: The way the json is formatted using `async: false` was the only way I found so far to be able to return it into a variable.. Removing it returns a console error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: You need to learn to work with asynchronous requests. Thoroughly study: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). The answer is a very good tutorial. Again that warning is telling you it might break soon

Comment: I do yes :) Okay thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of the `json`'s keys and choose a random one :

```js
let json = {
  "Hist eb zoso posclifos pit feaxald usow din regichics pi slaxanspeltaxatien": [
    "Paxarrot",
    "Paxarotto"
  ],
  "He dreto zo vech #1 whit sickros axabtol Paxaur VcCaxaltnoupp pi Ronnen": [
    "Vistaxaor Jaxangsen",
    "Vaxax Vaxaltin"
  ],
  "Hist eno eb zoso Jaxapaxanoso axarceheric wrints dis vaxado blem lico, yaxams pi woaxal el flewn sugaxal": [
    "Umosku",
    "Skestu"
  ],
  "Din pit 1581 spoost, JBK axanneuncow whis veen axamfitiens, fut axarse axangnewrodgow hist ethol chlaxatogupp": [
    "Naxavupp SOAR slaxainick",
    "Ismaxankrick zo"
  ]
}

let keys = Object.keys(json)

let random_key = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)]

let result = {};
result[random_key] = json[random_key]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is only bringing back a single value from the json tree, though. In the code snippet, the result `Paxarotto` I am looking to return it as a single array element `{
  "Hist eb zoso posclifos pit feaxald usow din regichics pi slaxanspeltaxatien": [
    "Paxarrot",
    "Paxarotto"
  ] }`

Comment: i edited the snippet to return an object like the one in your comment.

Comment: I see, perfect! Had not seen a reference anywhere to doing this method to return a single unique value, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.keys()`. It returns an array of the enumerable keys of an object.

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
var random = json[keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)]];
```